# How do I redirect user to 'home' page after validating his login data with database?

Tags: mysql, node.js

After checking login data (user name and password) I would like to redirect the valid user to home page.

Here is app. post:

```
    app.post('/', function ( req , res) {

    req.checkBody('home_user_name', 'User Name is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('home_password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();


pool.getConnection(function (error, tempCont) {
                if (!!error) {
        tempCont.release();
                    console.log('Error');
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Connected!');


                function get_role(callback) {


         console.log("look here >> " + req.body.home_user_name);
```

here is query:

```
   tempCont.query('SELECT * from `users` where `user_name` = ? ', [req.body.home_user_name] , function (error, results) {
                    if (error) callback(null);
                    callback(results[0].password);
                });
            }
```

here is the question how to redirect the valid user to home page? note that it is a function inside function inside app.post:

```
 get_role(function (data) {
                    if (data == req.body.home_password){


                    console.log("User Name is " + req.body.home_user_name + " and Password is " + data);
                 }
                    else {
                        console.log("passwords are not identical ");
                    }
                }
                );
```

here is errors validation:

```
   var errors = req.validationErrors();
            if (errors) {
                res.render('app', { errors: errors });
            } else {
                console.log("Validation: " + req.body.home_user_name);
            }
        }
    })
    })
```

Comment: How do I redirect user to 'home' page after validating his login data with database?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
res.redirect ('home');
```